# How do we calculate $ \iint_{D} (1-x-y)dxdy$ using polar coordinates?

Tags: integration

I have to calculate the following integral in polar coordinates:
$$
\iint\limits_D (1-x-y)dxdy=?
$$
where $D: x^2 + y^2 ⩽ R^2$.
I got the following
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta\int_0^{R} (1 - rcos\theta - rsin\theta)rdr
$$
My answer is $πR^2$ but I want to confirm if that's correct.

Comment: Hmm, why don't you just plug in mathematica and check?

Comment: That is right indeed.

Comment: @DonAntonio  Thank you!

Comment: If you encounter this or integrals which have a kind of symmetry you don't have to go to polar coordinates, kind of similar to how the integral of an odd function over $[-a,a]$ is 0, we have $f(x,y)=x+y$ is symmetrical over the disk. Specifically $f(-x,-y)=-f(x,y)$ which means the top right part exactly cancels with the bottom left part. So all you're left with is an integral of $1$ which is the area, $\pi R^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that such integral equals $\pi R^{2}$ (as you have suggested).

That is because the integral of $\sin$ or $\cos$ over a period equals zero.

Consequently, there is no need to evaluate the terms $r^{2}\cos(\theta)$ and $r^{2}\sin(\theta)$.

Hence it remains to calculate the integral:
\begin{align*}
I = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{0}^{R}r\mathrm{d}r
\end{align*}

which leads to the desired result.